# Apache2 Uninstallation Error Message

Tags: apache2, uninstall

I intend to uninstall apache2 by using

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

but got this lines of message. Where did I go wrong?

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  apache2  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 536 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 167732 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2 (2.4.34-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.10.1) ...
Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'

Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.4-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You have not yet fully configured `mysql-server-5.7` and that is why the `apt` process is complaining. It has nothing to do with Apache2. If you want to keep mysql, do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Otherwise, do `sudo apt purge mysql-server-5.7`.

Comment: Thank you, Jos. It turns out that the real problem is with my override.conf file, which previously I set to change mysql root password. After I emptied the file, I can uninstall mysql and apache2. Many thanks.